# How to include children with AS in borderContainer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Previously (Flex 3.5), I had used HBox and included TextInput boxes.  In Flex 4.x one must use BorderContainers; but the children don't show up when I use either the addElement or the addChild function.  How do I accomplish the task with AS in Flex 4.x?

```
//Flex 3.5
var twpBox:HBox = new HBox();
twpBox.id = "twp";
var ti1:TextInput = new TextInput();
ti1.id = "section";
var ti2:TextInput = new TextInput();
ti2.id = "township";
twpBox.addChild(ti1);
twpBox.addChild(ti2);

//Flex 4.x
var bcTest:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
var cmdOK:Button = new Button();
bcTest.addElement(cmdOK);
```

Answer (score 3):

HGroup might be more suitable as a replacement for HBox. Also try setting the label of the button and check it's position in  the debugger to actually see where it is. You also have to add the borderContainer or group to the stage.

```
var bcTest:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
var cmdOK:Button = new Button();
bcTest.addElement(cmdOK);
this.addElement(bcTest);
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out HGroup as a replacement for HBox.  One possible reason the items don't show up may be that the OP is not sizing them.  Or, if he's using the BorderContainer without specifying a layout other than basic; they may be stacked on top of each other; thus causing some of them not to display.